# Problema con los enlaces en laravel

Tags: laravel

He desarrollado una aplicación en laravel 5.5 y he añadido un template que he comprado. El problema lo tengo en el layout principal que es donde tengo las barras de menús superiores, horizontales y verticales y, en algunas vistas, no me respeta los hipervínculos. Por ejemplo:

Tengo este boton: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual es el menú desplegable de administración del usuario y ajustes, es dropdown menu, os pongo el código del layout padre del que extiende esta vista:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <a href="{{ url('/worker/show/.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)') }}" class="dropdown-item">
    <i class="icon-head"></i> Editar Perfil</a>
    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="dropdown-item" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
</div>
```

Si inspecciono el código veo que ese enlace que pone `"worker/show...` no funciona, aquí está el código de inspección:

```
<a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-user-link" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="avatar avatar-online">
        <img src="/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-1.png" alt="avatar"><i></i>
    </span>
    <span class="user-name">Admin</span>
</a>
```

El dropdown no se despliega, pero solo me pasa en algunas vistas. ¿A qué se debe esto? ¿Es que no estoy extendiendo bien las vistas? Todas las vistas extienden del layout padre y tienen las secciones bien definidas. Os puedo poner el código de las vistas si lo necesitáis.

Gracias por la atención. Un saludo.

Edito: 
 Rutas:

```
Route::get('/worker/show/{id_worker}', 'UserController@show');
//rutas accessibles solo para el usuario administrador
Route::group(['middleware' => 'usuarioAdmin'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    //Rutas empleados
});
//rutas accessibles solo para el usuario standard
Route::group(['middleware' => 'usuarioStandard'], function () {
    Route::get('/vacation/create', 'VacationController@index');
    Route::get('/vacation/creat/{id_worker}/{name_worker}', 'VacationController@create');

});
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tus rutas del archivo `routes.php` a las que haces uso en tu código HTML, por favor?

Comment: editada, gracias por tu atención :)

Comment: Si corres el comando `php artisan route:list`, ¿cómo te imprime la consola esta ruta `Route::get('/worker/show/{id_worker}', 'UserController@show');`?

Comment: |        | GET|HEAD | worker/show/{id_worker}                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                               | web                      |
Realmente no creo que sea culpa de la ruta, si no no funcionaria en ninguna vista. Parece como si las vistas hijas no reciben los hipervinculos del layout padre.

Comment: Yo siento que si tiene que ver ya que el método helper de laravel `url()` no arroja error si la url no está registrada. Si colocas la ruta `Route::get('/worker/show/{id_worker}', 'UserController@show');` afuera del `Route::group`, ¿te sigue apareciendo en blanco?, yo sé que tiene que quedar dentro del middleware, pero trata poniéndola afuera por favor

Comment: jejeje me adelante a ti, ya probe eso, y hace exactamente lo mismo, fue lo primero que pense, que fuera culpa del middleware aunque tampoco tendria mucho sentido. Pero no, no funciona, edito las rutas para que veas como lo tengo ahora, pero bueno eso...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82304/discussion-between-aaron-gutierrez-and-david-pazo-lopez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdadera respuesta a este problema, aparte de lo que indicó Shassain, que está en lo correcto, fue que se estaba incluyendo dos veces bootstrap y jQuery y hubo una confusión con hipervínculos que estaba provocando. El link siempre se imprimió, sólo que estaba escondido.

Es recomendable utilizar el método `route()` en vez de `url()` ya que el método `url()` lo único que hace es ayudarte a crear la cadena después de tu dominio, el método no verificará que exista la ruta registrada, te imprimirá lo que sea que le pongas dentro de ella, tampoco te imprime null.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer solo tienes un error de sintaxis, en :

```
<a href="{{ url('/worker/show/.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)') }}" class="dropdown-item">
```

Con un error en el punto (.) entre el `show/.Crypt`... y lo que siga, punto por el cual la ruta no es encontrada y no se muestra en html.

El formato correcto seria:

```
<a href="{{ url('/worker/show/'.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)) }}" class="dropdown-item">
```

Comment: Si es cierto, no lo había visto pero, aún así, no imprimiría blanco sino más bien literal esto `/worker/show/'.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id`, ¿no?

Comment: el helper url solo busca una ruta valida, en caso de no encontrarla solo arroja null, cosa que no se refleja en html, si deseas que todo valla correcto, te recomiendo utilizar el helper `route` y no el `url`, claro que para esto debes de definir el `->name('miruta')` en tus rutas.

Comment: Bueno, ojalá si solucione el problema de David, también añadiría que no es considerada una buena práctica poner inline event handlers en el HTML(el `onclick` que tiene) , por cuestiones de legibilidad de código y mantenimiento, al igual que ese código jamás sería cacheado por el navegador, puede que si afecte el rendimiento si se abusa de esa sintaxis.

Comment: Lo he arreglado, y sigue haciendo lo mismo, ese error me lo tiraria despues de desplegar el menu, disculpa que me haya explicado tan mal, se que es algo confuso, pero el problema es el desplegable, ya sabia que ese enlace estaba mal, pero es que lo de Auth:user()->id para coger el id, es lo que no me funciona que estoy trabajando en ello, de hecho podria omitirlo pero seguiria sin desplegarse el menu

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez, Intenta poner la url-enlace en otro lugar y sin css,class o id, en caso de que si funcione, lo unico que se me viene a la mente que la clase de `dropdown-item` borre la url, y no sea problema de laravel.

Comment: probado y hace lo mismo... u.u Gracias por tu ayuda @Shassain

Comment: He visto que me da error en una libreria que no consigue cargar.